# Question regarding cyclic subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional field and let $\vec v \in V$ ($\vec v \neq \vec 0$) such that $\operatorname{Span}${$\vec v, T(\vec v), T^2(\vec v),...$}$\neq V$

If $\vec w\notin \operatorname{Span}${$\vec v, T(\vec v), T^2(\vec v),...$} can we guarantee that $T(\vec w)\notin \operatorname{Span}${$\vec v, T(\vec v), T^2(\vec v),...$} ?

Comment: No: $\vec w$ might be in $\ker T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $T$ be the map $$T\colon (a,b)\mapsto (a,0).$$
Then, choose $v=(1,0)$, you have $\mathrm{span}(v,T(v),\dots,)=\mathrm{span}(v)\not=V$. Then choose $w=(1,1)\notin \mathrm{span}(v,T(v),\dots,)$ and observe that $T(w)=v\in \mathrm{span}(v,T(v),\dots,)$.

Comment: You're welcome.